Is it right to say that God is an efficient cause?
Is it right to say that God is an efficient cause in the context of Thomistic Christian theology? I ask because of the following:
It seems that God is not an efficient cause.
For if God is an efficient cause he would be placed in the genus of efficient causes. Yet God cannot be in a genus. And this is for the following reasons.
One: Anything that is in a genus has something besides its generic essence (Compendium of Theology 1:12). However, God is existence itself (Compendium of Theology 1:12). And this existence is universally perfect (Summa Theologica 1:4:2).
As such, this divine existence does not lack any perfection which may be found in any genus. Hence nothing can be added to it. Thus, God is not in any genus. And as such, God is not in the genus of efficient causes. And as such, God is not an efficient cause.
Two: Genus is in passive potency to specific differences (Compendium of Theology 1:12). As such, in every being composed of genus and differences, act is mixed with passive potency (Compendium of Theology 1:12). However, there is no passive potency in God.
For that which has passive potency is possibly non-existent as regards to whatever it has of potentiality (Summa Contra Gentiles 1:16). Yet God cannot not be (Summa Contra Gentiles 1:16). For God is eternal (Summa Contra Gentiles 1:16).
Thus, God is not in any genus. And as such, God is not in the genus of efficient causes. And as such, God is not an efficient cause.

Per Aquinas God is existence itself (Compendium of Theology 1:12) which is unlike any created being that has existence as an attribute rather than as an essence. For any being in a Thomistic genus, there is a distinction between its essence and existence acting as his genus conditional's implicit material antecedent. Since God’s essence and existence are identical per Aquinas, God cannot be categorized under any genus because the above antecedent fails to hold. Unlike Scotus, Aquinas hold that God is a cause by analogy rather than univocally, which is pure act without any contingent potency...

@DoubleKnot I feel that would make a good answer with a little extension.

This question is similar to: How can God be in the genus of efficient causes?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, Thomas Aquinas considers God an efficient cause. In Summa Theologiae I, Quaestio 2, Art. 3 Thomas says in describing the second way to prove God’s existence:

“Ergo est necesse ponere aliquam causam efficientem primam: quam omnes
Deum nominant.” (Therefore it is necessary to admit a first efficient
cause, to which everyone gives the name of God.)

